# OpenGL ES 2.0 to Video on iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, video, xcode4, opengl-es-2.0, avassetwriter

I am at my wits end here despite the good information here on StackOverflow...

I am trying to write an OpenGL renderbuffer to a video on the iPad 2 (using iOS 4.3). This is more exactly what I am attempting:

A) set up an AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor

1. create an AVAssetWriter that points to a video file
2. set up an AVAssetWriterInput with appropriate settings
3. set up an AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor to add data to the video file

B) write data to a video file using that AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor

1. render OpenGL code to the screen
2. get the OpenGL buffer via glReadPixels
3. create a CVPixelBufferRef from the OpenGL data
4. append that PixelBuffer to the AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor using the appendPixelBuffer method

However, I am having problems doings this. My strategy right now is to set up the AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor when a button is pressed. Once the AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor is valid, I set a flag to signal the EAGLView to create a pixel buffer and append it to the video file via appendPixelBuffer for a given number of frames.

Right now my code is crashing as it tries to append the second pixel buffer, giving me the following error:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x131db0
```

Here is my AVAsset setup code (a lot of was based on Rudy Aramayo's code, which *does* work on normal images, but is not set up for textures):

```
- (void) testVideoWriter {

  //initialize global info
  MOVIE_NAME = @"Documents/Movie.mov";
  CGSize size = CGSizeMake(480, 320);
  frameLength = CMTimeMake(1, 5); 
  currentTime = kCMTimeZero;
  currentFrame = 0;

  NSString *MOVIE_PATH = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:MOVIE_NAME];
  NSError *error = nil;

  unlink([betaCompressionDirectory UTF8String]);

  videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:betaCompressionDirectory] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];

  NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey, nil];
  writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];

  //writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;

  NSDictionary *sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

  adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput                                                                          sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary];
  [adaptor retain];

  [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

  [videoWriter startWriting];
  [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

  VIDEO_WRITER_IS_READY = true;
}
```

Ok, now that my videoWriter and adaptor are set up, I tell my OpenGL renderer to create a pixel buffer for every frame:

```
- (void) captureScreenVideo {

  if (!writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
    return;
  }

  CGSize esize = CGSizeMake(eagl.backingWidth, eagl.backingHeight);
  NSInteger myDataLength = esize.width * esize.height * 4;
  GLuint *buffer = (GLuint *) malloc(myDataLength);
  glReadPixels(0, 0, esize.width, esize.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
  CVPixelBufferRef pixel_buffer = NULL;
  CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes (NULL, esize.width, esize.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, buffer, 4 * esize.width, NULL, 0, NULL, &pixel_buffer);

  /* DON'T FREE THIS BEFORE USING pixel_buffer! */ 
  //free(buffer);

  if(![adaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixel_buffer withPresentationTime:currentTime]) {
      NSLog(@"FAIL");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Success:%d", currentFrame);
      currentTime = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, frameLength);
    }

   free(buffer);
   CVPixelBufferRelease(pixel_buffer);
  }


  currentFrame++;

  if (currentFrame > MAX_FRAMES) {
    VIDEO_WRITER_IS_READY = false;
    [writerInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];
    [videoWriter release];

    [self moveVideoToSavedPhotos]; 
  }
}
```

And finally, I move the Video to the camera roll:

```
- (void) moveVideoToSavedPhotos {
  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  NSString *localVid = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:MOVIE_NAME];    
  NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localVid];

  [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:fileURL
                              completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                if (error) {   
                                  NSLog(@"%@: Error saving context: %@", [self class], [error localizedDescription]);
                                }
                              }];
  [library release];
}
```

However, as I said, I am crashing in the call to appendPixelBuffer.

Sorry for sending so much code, but I really don't know what I am doing wrong. It seemed like it would be trivial to update a project which writes images to a video, but I am unable to take the pixel buffer I create via glReadPixels and append it. It's driving me crazy! If anyone has any advice or a working code example of OpenGL --> Video that would be amazing... Thanks!

Comment: I updated the code above by adding the line "[adaptor retain];" directly after creating the adaptor, and that prevents my code from crashing! However, now I have a new issue with this code... it's writing 40 frames of black pixels... I can see that my glReadPixels is in fact reading pixels, but somehow during the creation of the pixel buffer, during the appending, or during the file transfer there is an issue...

Comment: I've left the code above and the question because I would like to get feedback on whether or not this is a good strategy for saving OpenGL data to video. Also, I am still not able to actually save the video...

Comment: Well there's nothing like writing a long explanation of what's not working to help clarify the issues... I just tested this on the iPad Simulator (instead of the actual device). On the simulator this code *works* perfectly!!! However, it is still showing only black or empty frames on the actual iPad... I am not sure if it is an issue with transferring the video to the camera roll or something wonky with the pixel buffer.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this, I got this to work finally... and understand a bit more about it now than I did. I had an error in the above code where I was freeing the data buffer filled from glReadPixels _before_ calling appendPixelBuffer. That is, I thought it was safe to free it since I had already created the CVPixelBufferRef. I've edited the code above so the pixel buffer actual has data now!

Comment: It looks like specifying a `CVPixelBufferReleaseBytesCallback` argument that takes care of freeing the backing-buffer you allocated is the right way to do this. The pixel buffer that you pass to the adaptor may be accessed asynchronously and therefore you shouldn't expect that your subsequent `CFPixelBufferRelease` call is the point at which the underlying memory is to be freed as well. The adaptor may at that point still need those bytes. In fact, the `appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime:` doc says "Do not modify a CVPixelBuffer or its contents after you have passed it to this method."

Comment: Angus, I'm trying to use some of this code and end up in "FAIL" right at the beginning (when currentTime is still Zero). I'm not sure why.

Comment: Actually, where/when do you call your "captureScreenVideo" method? Not totally sure either. I'm pretty new to OpenGL, although I have over 3 years experience with the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just got something similar to this working in my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework, based on the above code, so I thought I'd provide my working solution to this. In my case, I was able to use a pixel buffer pool, as suggested by Srikumar, instead of the manually created pixel buffers for each frame.

I first configure the movie to be recorded:

```
NSError *error = nil;

assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:movieURL fileType:AVFileTypeAppleM4V error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}


NSMutableDictionary * outputSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[outputSettings setObject: AVVideoCodecH264 forKey: AVVideoCodecKey];
[outputSettings setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: videoSize.width] forKey: AVVideoWidthKey];
[outputSettings setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: videoSize.height] forKey: AVVideoHeightKey];


assetWriterVideoInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:outputSettings];
assetWriterVideoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

// You need to use BGRA for the video in order to get realtime encoding. I use a color-swizzling shader to line up glReadPixels' normal RGBA output with the movie input's BGRA.
NSDictionary *sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:videoSize.width], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:videoSize.height], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                                                       nil];

assetWriterPixelBufferInput = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:assetWriterVideoInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary];

[assetWriter addInput:assetWriterVideoInput];
```

then use this code to grab each rendered frame using `glReadPixels()`:

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixel_buffer = NULL;

CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer (NULL, [assetWriterPixelBufferInput pixelBufferPool], &pixel_buffer);
if ((pixel_buffer == NULL) || (status != kCVReturnSuccess))
{
    return;
}
else
{
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixel_buffer, 0);
    GLubyte *pixelBufferData = (GLubyte *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixel_buffer);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBufferData);
}

// May need to add a check here, because if two consecutive times with the same value are added to the movie, it aborts recording
CMTime currentTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime],120);

if(![assetWriterPixelBufferInput appendPixelBuffer:pixel_buffer withPresentationTime:currentTime]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Problem appending pixel buffer at time: %lld", currentTime.value);
} 
else 
{
//        NSLog(@"Recorded pixel buffer at time: %lld", currentTime.value);
}
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixel_buffer, 0);

CVPixelBufferRelease(pixel_buffer);
```

One thing I noticed is that if I tried to append two pixel buffers with the same integer time value (in the basis provided), the entire recording would fail and the input would never take another pixel buffer. Similarly, if I tried to append a pixel buffer after retrieval from the pool failed, it would abort the recording. Thus, the early bailout in the code above.

In addition to the above code, I use a color-swizzling shader to convert the RGBA rendering in my OpenGL ES scene to BGRA for fast encoding by the AVAssetWriter. With this, I'm able to record 640x480 video at 30 FPS on an iPhone 4.

Again, all of the code for this can be found within the [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) repository, under the GPUImageMovieWriter class.

Comment: I don't understand, using your code, the pixelBufferPool is never property of the pixel buffer input is never created. Any idea why?

Comment: Note to self: make sure the file doesn't already exist when calling [assetWriter startWriting]

Comment: @sharvey - Yup, that will get you every time. Caused me more than a little frustration until I figured that out.

Comment: Hmm it creates a black video in the simulator (not tried on a device) for me :/

Comment: @Dimillian77 - If using `glReadPixels()`, make sure that is used after your content is rendered, but before your render buffer is presented to the screen. If you attempt to read pixels after that, you'll only get back black. Also, the Simulator has some issues with movie content, I've seen.

Comment: Even if I turn kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking to YES on my GLKView? Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: @BradLarson Tried on the device, same.

Comment: @Dimillian77 - Retained backing should let you read the contents after presenting the render buffer to the screen, but will slow down your overall rendering. I've also heard reports that it doesn't always work right for a GLKView. I prefer to use a texture-backed FBO and the faster capture from the texture caches, or have a means of triggering glReadPixels right before presenting the render buffer.

Comment: @BradLarson Okay, I tried many things, but I'm still stuck :/ Here is my code if you want to look at it (or not :p) https://gist.github.com/Dimillian/e52165e5367339013c55

Comment: And I tried the GPUMovieWrite class from your framework, but I'm not sure on how to plug it to my GLKView subclass.

Comment: @Dimillian77 - All of that's probably best asked in a new question.

Comment: @BradLarson It's really similar in the end, but yeah, I'll open a new question.

Comment: No hopes to achieve something equivalent, but for SpriteKit, any time soon right? I mean, the "make sure that is used after your content is rendered, but before your render buffer is presented to the screen" part seems a bit un-implementable with what SpriteKit currently exposes...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a few things to do here -

1. According to the docs, it looks like the recommended way to create a pixel buffer is to use `CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer` on the `adaptor.pixelBufferPool`.
2. You can then fill in the buffer by getting the address using `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress` followed by `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress` and unlocking the memory using `CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress` before passing it to the adaptor.
3. The pixel buffer can be passed to the input when `writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData` is `YES`. This means a "wait until ready". A `usleep` until it becomes `YES` works, but you can also use key-value observing.

The rest of the stuff is alright. With this much, the original code results in a playable video file.

Answer (score 2):

“In case anyone stumbles across this, I got this to work finally... and understand a bit more about it now than I did. I had an error in the above code where I was freeing the data buffer filled from glReadPixels before calling appendPixelBuffer. That is, I thought it was safe to free it since I had already created the CVPixelBufferRef. I've edited the code above so the pixel buffer actual has data now! – Angus Forbes Jun 28 '11 at 5:58”

this is the real reason for your crash, i met this problem too.
Do not free the buffer even if you have created the CVPixelBufferRef.

Comment: can you post your source code for somebody to review?  I'm doing something similar and it would be great to see what you did to get started.  --Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like improper memory management. The fact the error states that the message was sent to `__NSCFDictionary` instead of `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` is highly suspicious.

Why do you need to `retain` the adaptor manually? This looks hacky since CocoaTouch is fully [ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385212/how-does-the-new-automatic-reference-counting-mechanism-work).

[Here's a starter](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial) to nail down the memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

from your error message `-[__NSCFDictionary appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x131db0`
Looks like a your pixelBufferAdapter was released and now its pointing to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The only code I've ever gotten to work for this is at:

https://demonicactivity.blogspot.com/2016/11/tech-serious-ios-developers-use-every.html

```
  // [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // To capture the output to an OpenGL render buffer...
        NSInteger myDataLength = _backingWidth * _backingHeight * 4;
        GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 8);
        glReadPixels(0, 0, _backingWidth, _backingHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        // To swap the pixel buffer to a CoreGraphics context (as a CGImage)
        CGDataProviderRef provider;
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef;
        CGImageRef imageRef;
        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
        @try {
            provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, myDataLength, &releaseDataCallback);
            int bitsPerComponent = 8;
            int bitsPerPixel = 32;
            int bytesPerRow = 4 * _backingWidth;
            colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
            CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
            imageRef = CGImageCreate(_backingWidth, _backingHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
        } @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", [exception reason]);
        } @finally {
            if (imageRef) {
                // To convert the CGImage to a pixel buffer (for writing to a file using AVAssetWriter)
                pixelBuffer = [CVCGImageUtil pixelBufferFromCGImage:imageRef];
                // To verify the integrity of the pixel buffer (by converting it back to a CGIImage, and thendisplaying it in a layer)
                imageLayer.contents = (__bridge id)[CVCGImageUtil cgImageFromPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer context:_ciContext];
            }
            CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
            CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        }

    }
});
```

.
.
.

The callback to free the data in the instance of the CGDataProvider class:

```
static void releaseDataCallback (void *info, const void *data, size_t size) {
    free((void*)data);
}
```

The CVCGImageUtil class interface and implementation files, respectively:

```
@import Foundation;
@import CoreMedia;
@import CoreGraphics;
@import QuartzCore;
@import CoreImage;
@import UIKit;

@interface CVCGImageUtil : NSObject

+ (CGImageRef)cgImageFromPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer context:(CIContext *)context;

+ (CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image;

+ (CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image;

@end

#import "CVCGImageUtil.h"

@implementation CVCGImageUtil

+ (CGImageRef)cgImageFromPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer context:(CIContext *)context
{
    // CVPixelBuffer to CoreImage
    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
    image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
    CGPoint origin = [image extent].origin;
    image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-origin.x, -origin.y)];

    // CoreImage to CGImage via CoreImage context
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:[image extent]];

    // CGImage to UIImage (OPTIONAL)
    //UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    //return (CGImageRef)uiImage.CGImage;

    return cgImage;
}

+ (CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image
{
    CGSize frameSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                  CGImageGetHeight(image));
    NSDictionary *options =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
     kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
     kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
     nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

    CVReturn status =
    CVPixelBufferCreate(
                        kCFAllocatorDefault, frameSize.width, frameSize.height,
                        kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options,
                        &pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                 pxdata, frameSize.width, frameSize.height,
                                                 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pxbuffer),
                                                 rgbColorSpace,
                                                 (CGBitmapInfo)kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little |
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}

+ (CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [CVCGImageUtil pixelBufferFromCGImage:image];
    CMSampleBufferRef newSampleBuffer = NULL;
    CMSampleTimingInfo timimgInfo = kCMTimingInfoInvalid;
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoInfo = NULL;
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(
                                                 NULL, pixelBuffer, &videoInfo);
    CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       pixelBuffer,
                                       true,
                                       NULL,
                                       NULL,
                                       videoInfo,
                                       &timimgInfo,
                                       &newSampleBuffer);

    return newSampleBuffer;
}

@end
```

That answers part B of your question, to-the-letter. Part A follows in a separate answer...

Answer (score 0):

I've never failed to read and write a video file to iPhone with this code; in your implementation, you will simply need to substitute the calls in the processFrame method, found at the end of the implementation method, to calls to whatever methods to which you pass pixel buffers as parameters to its equivalent, and otherwise modify that method to return the pixel buffer generated as per the sample code above--that's basic, so you should be okay:

```
//
//  ExportVideo.h
//  ChromaFilterTest
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 10/30/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import "GLKitView.h"

@interface ExportVideo : NSObject
{
    AVURLAsset                           *_asset;
    AVAssetReader                        *_reader;
    AVAssetWriter                        *_writer;
    NSString                             *_outputURL;
    NSURL                                *_outURL;
    AVAssetReaderTrackOutput             *_readerAudioOutput;
    AVAssetWriterInput                   *_writerAudioInput;
    AVAssetReaderTrackOutput             *_readerVideoOutput;
    AVAssetWriterInput                   *_writerVideoInput;
    CVPixelBufferRef                      _currentBuffer;
    dispatch_queue_t                      _mainSerializationQueue;
    dispatch_queue_t                      _rwAudioSerializationQueue;
    dispatch_queue_t                      _rwVideoSerializationQueue;
    dispatch_group_t                      _dispatchGroup;
    BOOL                                  _cancelled;
    BOOL                                  _audioFinished;
    BOOL                                  _videoFinished;
    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *_pixelBufferAdaptor;
}

@property (readwrite, retain) NSURL *url;
@property (readwrite, retain) GLKitView *renderer;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url usingRenderer:(GLKitView *)renderer;
- (void)startProcessing;
@end


//
//  ExportVideo.m
//  ChromaFilterTest
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 10/30/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ExportVideo.h"
#import "GLKitView.h"

@implementation ExportVideo

@synthesize url = _url;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url usingRenderer:(GLKitView *)renderer {
    NSLog(@"ExportVideo");
    if (!(self = [super init])) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.url = url;
    self.renderer = renderer;

    NSString *serializationQueueDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ serialization queue", self];
    _mainSerializationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([serializationQueueDescription UTF8String], NULL);

    NSString *rwAudioSerializationQueueDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ rw audio serialization queue", self];
    _rwAudioSerializationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([rwAudioSerializationQueueDescription UTF8String], NULL);

    NSString *rwVideoSerializationQueueDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ rw video serialization queue", self];
    _rwVideoSerializationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([rwVideoSerializationQueueDescription UTF8String], NULL);

    return self;
}

- (void)startProcessing {
    NSDictionary *inputOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey];
    _asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:self.url options:inputOptions];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", self.url);
    _cancelled = NO;
    [_asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler: ^{
        dispatch_async(_mainSerializationQueue, ^{
            if (_cancelled)
                return;
            BOOL success = YES;
            NSError *localError = nil;
            success = ([_asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&localError] == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded);
            if (success)
            {
                NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                NSString *localOutputPath = [self.url path];
                if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:localOutputPath])
                    //success = [fm removeItemAtPath:localOutputPath error:&localError];
                    success = TRUE;
            }
            if (success)
                success = [self setupAssetReaderAndAssetWriter:&localError];
            if (success)
                success = [self startAssetReaderAndWriter:&localError];
            if (!success)
                [self readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:success withError:localError];
        });
    }];
}


- (BOOL)setupAssetReaderAndAssetWriter:(NSError **)outError
{
    // Create and initialize the asset reader.
    _reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:_asset error:outError];
    BOOL success = (_reader != nil);
    if (success)
    {
        // If the asset reader was successfully initialized, do the same for the asset writer.
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        _outputURL = paths[0];
        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [manager createDirectoryAtPath:_outputURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
        _outputURL = [_outputURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];
        [manager removeItemAtPath:_outputURL error:nil];
        _outURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_outputURL];
        _writer = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:_outURL fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:outError];
        success = (_writer != nil);
    }

    if (success)
    {
        // If the reader and writer were successfully initialized, grab the audio and video asset tracks that will be used.
        AVAssetTrack *assetAudioTrack = nil, *assetVideoTrack = nil;
        NSArray *audioTracks = [_asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
        if ([audioTracks count] > 0)
            assetAudioTrack = [audioTracks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *videoTracks = [_asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([videoTracks count] > 0)
            assetVideoTrack = [videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];

        if (assetAudioTrack)
        {
            // If there is an audio track to read, set the decompression settings to Linear PCM and create the asset reader output.
            NSDictionary *decompressionAudioSettings = @{ AVFormatIDKey : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] };
            _readerAudioOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:assetAudioTrack outputSettings:decompressionAudioSettings];
            [_reader addOutput:_readerAudioOutput];
            // Then, set the compression settings to 128kbps AAC and create the asset writer input.
            AudioChannelLayout stereoChannelLayout = {
                .mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo,
                .mChannelBitmap = 0,
                .mNumberChannelDescriptions = 0
            };
            NSData *channelLayoutAsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&stereoChannelLayout length:offsetof(AudioChannelLayout, mChannelDescriptions)];
            NSDictionary *compressionAudioSettings = @{
                                                       AVFormatIDKey         : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],
                                                       AVEncoderBitRateKey   : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:128000],
                                                       AVSampleRateKey       : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:44100],
                                                       AVChannelLayoutKey    : channelLayoutAsData,
                                                       AVNumberOfChannelsKey : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:2]
                                                       };
            _writerAudioInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:[assetAudioTrack mediaType] outputSettings:compressionAudioSettings];
            [_writer addInput:_writerAudioInput];
        }

        if (assetVideoTrack)
        {
            // If there is a video track to read, set the decompression settings for YUV and create the asset reader output.
            NSDictionary *decompressionVideoSettings = @{
                                                         (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey     : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange],
                                                         (id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey : [NSDictionary dictionary]
                                                         };
            _readerVideoOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:assetVideoTrack outputSettings:decompressionVideoSettings];
            [_reader addOutput:_readerVideoOutput];
            CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = NULL;
            // Grab the video format descriptions from the video track and grab the first one if it exists.
            NSArray *formatDescriptions = [assetVideoTrack formatDescriptions];
            if ([formatDescriptions count] > 0)
                formatDescription = (__bridge CMFormatDescriptionRef)[formatDescriptions objectAtIndex:0];
            CGSize trackDimensions = {
                .width = 0.0,
                .height = 0.0,
            };
            // If the video track had a format description, grab the track dimensions from there. Otherwise, grab them direcly from the track itself.
            if (formatDescription)
                trackDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetPresentationDimensions(formatDescription, false, false);
            else
                trackDimensions = [assetVideoTrack naturalSize];
            NSDictionary *compressionSettings = nil;
            // If the video track had a format description, attempt to grab the clean aperture settings and pixel aspect ratio used by the video.
            if (formatDescription)
            {
                NSDictionary *cleanAperture = nil;
                NSDictionary *pixelAspectRatio = nil;
                CFDictionaryRef cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription = CMFormatDescriptionGetExtension(formatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_CleanAperture);
                if (cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription)
                {
                    cleanAperture = @{
                                      AVVideoCleanApertureWidthKey            : (id)CFDictionaryGetValue(cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_CleanApertureWidth),
                                      AVVideoCleanApertureHeightKey           : (id)CFDictionaryGetValue(cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_CleanApertureHeight),
                                      AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey : (id)CFDictionaryGetValue(cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_CleanApertureHorizontalOffset),
                                      AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey   : (id)CFDictionaryGetValue(cleanApertureFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_CleanApertureVerticalOffset)
                                      };
                }
                CFDictionaryRef pixelAspectRatioFromCMFormatDescription = CMFormatDescriptionGetExtension(formatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_PixelAspectRatio);
                if (pixelAspectRatioFromCMFormatDescription)
                {
                    pixelAspectRatio = @{
                                         AVVideoPixelAspectRatioHorizontalSpacingKey : (id)CFDictionaryGetValue(pixelAspectRatioFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_PixelAspectRatioHorizontalSpacing),
                                         AVVideoPixelAspectRatioVerticalSpacingKey   : (id)CFDictionaryGetValue(pixelAspectRatioFromCMFormatDescription, kCMFormatDescriptionKey_PixelAspectRatioVerticalSpacing)
                                         };
                }
                // Add whichever settings we could grab from the format description to the compression settings dictionary.
                if (cleanAperture || pixelAspectRatio)
                {
                    NSMutableDictionary *mutableCompressionSettings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    if (cleanAperture)
                        [mutableCompressionSettings setObject:cleanAperture forKey:AVVideoCleanApertureKey];
                    if (pixelAspectRatio)
                        [mutableCompressionSettings setObject:pixelAspectRatio forKey:AVVideoPixelAspectRatioKey];
                    compressionSettings = mutableCompressionSettings;
                }
            }
            // Create the video settings dictionary for H.264.
            NSMutableDictionary *videoSettings = (NSMutableDictionary *) @{
                                                                           AVVideoCodecKey  : AVVideoCodecH264,
                                                                           AVVideoWidthKey  : [NSNumber numberWithDouble:trackDimensions.width],
                                                                           AVVideoHeightKey : [NSNumber numberWithDouble:trackDimensions.height]
                                                                           };
            // Put the compression settings into the video settings dictionary if we were able to grab them.
            if (compressionSettings)
                [videoSettings setObject:compressionSettings forKey:AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey];
            // Create the asset writer input and add it to the asset writer.
            _writerVideoInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:[assetVideoTrack mediaType] outputSettings:videoSettings];
            NSDictionary *pixelBufferAdaptorSettings = @{
                                                         (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey     : @(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange),
                                                         (id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey : [NSDictionary dictionary],
                                                         (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey               : [NSNumber numberWithDouble:trackDimensions.width],
                                                         (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey              : [NSNumber numberWithDouble:trackDimensions.height]
                                                         };

            _pixelBufferAdaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:_writerVideoInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:pixelBufferAdaptorSettings];

            [_writer addInput:_writerVideoInput];
        }
    }
    return success;
}

- (BOOL)startAssetReaderAndWriter:(NSError **)outError
{
    BOOL success = YES;
    // Attempt to start the asset reader.
    success = [_reader startReading];
    if (!success) {
        *outError = [_reader error];
        NSLog(@"Reader error");
    }
    if (success)
    {
        // If the reader started successfully, attempt to start the asset writer.
        success = [_writer startWriting];
        if (!success) {
            *outError = [_writer error];
            NSLog(@"Writer error");
        }
    }

    if (success)
    {
        // If the asset reader and writer both started successfully, create the dispatch group where the reencoding will take place and start a sample-writing session.
        _dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();
        [_writer startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
        _audioFinished = NO;
        _videoFinished = NO;

        if (_writerAudioInput)
        {
            // If there is audio to reencode, enter the dispatch group before beginning the work.
            dispatch_group_enter(_dispatchGroup);
            // Specify the block to execute when the asset writer is ready for audio media data, and specify the queue to call it on.
            [_writerAudioInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:_rwAudioSerializationQueue usingBlock:^{
                // Because the block is called asynchronously, check to see whether its task is complete.
                if (_audioFinished)
                    return;
                BOOL completedOrFailed = NO;
                // If the task isn't complete yet, make sure that the input is actually ready for more media data.
                while ([_writerAudioInput isReadyForMoreMediaData] && !completedOrFailed)
                {
                    // Get the next audio sample buffer, and append it to the output file.
                    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [_readerAudioOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
                    if (sampleBuffer != NULL)
                    {
                        BOOL success = [_writerAudioInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
                        sampleBuffer = NULL;
                        completedOrFailed = !success;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completedOrFailed = YES;
                    }
                }
                if (completedOrFailed)
                {
                    // Mark the input as finished, but only if we haven't already done so, and then leave the dispatch group (since the audio work has finished).
                    BOOL oldFinished = _audioFinished;
                    _audioFinished = YES;
                    if (oldFinished == NO)
                    {
                        [_writerAudioInput markAsFinished];
                    }
                    dispatch_group_leave(_dispatchGroup);
                }
            }];
        }

        if (_writerVideoInput)
        {
            // If we had video to reencode, enter the dispatch group before beginning the work.
            dispatch_group_enter(_dispatchGroup);
            // Specify the block to execute when the asset writer is ready for video media data, and specify the queue to call it on.
            [_writerVideoInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:_rwVideoSerializationQueue usingBlock:^{
                // Because the block is called asynchronously, check to see whether its task is complete.
                if (_videoFinished)
                    return;
                BOOL completedOrFailed = NO;
                // If the task isn't complete yet, make sure that the input is actually ready for more media data.
                while ([_writerVideoInput isReadyForMoreMediaData] && !completedOrFailed)
                {
                    // Get the next video sample buffer, and append it to the output file.
                    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [_readerVideoOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

                    CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
                    _currentBuffer = pixelBuffer;
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processFrame) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

                    if (_currentBuffer != NULL)
                    {
                        //BOOL success = [_writerVideoInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                        BOOL success = [_pixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:_currentBuffer withPresentationTime:CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)];
                        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
                        sampleBuffer = NULL;
                        completedOrFailed = !success;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completedOrFailed = YES;
                    }
                }
                if (completedOrFailed)
                {
                    // Mark the input as finished, but only if we haven't already done so, and then leave the dispatch group (since the video work has finished).
                    BOOL oldFinished = _videoFinished;
                    _videoFinished = YES;
                    if (oldFinished == NO)
                    {
                        [_writerVideoInput markAsFinished];
                    }
                    dispatch_group_leave(_dispatchGroup);
                }
            }];
        }
        // Set up the notification that the dispatch group will send when the audio and video work have both finished.
        dispatch_group_notify(_dispatchGroup, _mainSerializationQueue, ^{
            BOOL finalSuccess = YES;
            NSError *finalError = nil;
            // Check to see if the work has finished due to cancellation.
            if (_cancelled)
            {
                // If so, cancel the reader and writer.
                [_reader cancelReading];
                [_writer cancelWriting];
            }
            else
            {
                // If cancellation didn't occur, first make sure that the asset reader didn't fail.
                if ([_reader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusFailed)
                {
                    finalSuccess = NO;
                    finalError = [_reader error];
                    NSLog(@"_reader finalError: %@", finalError);
                }
                // If the asset reader didn't fail, attempt to stop the asset writer and check for any errors.
                [_writer finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
                    [self readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:finalSuccess withError:[_writer error]];
                }];
            }
            // Call the method to handle completion, and pass in the appropriate parameters to indicate whether reencoding was successful.

        });
    }
    // Return success here to indicate whether the asset reader and writer were started successfully.
    return success;
}

- (void)readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:(BOOL)success withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (!success)
    {
        // If the reencoding process failed, we need to cancel the asset reader and writer.
        [_reader cancelReading];
        [_writer cancelWriting];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Handle any UI tasks here related to failure.
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // Reencoding was successful, reset booleans.
        _cancelled = NO;
        _videoFinished = NO;
        _audioFinished = NO;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(_outputURL, nil, nil, nil);
        });
    }
    NSLog(@"readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully success = %@ : Error = %@", (success == 0) ? @"NO" : @"YES", error);
}

- (void)processFrame {

    if (_currentBuffer) {
        if (kCVReturnSuccess == CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(_currentBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly))
        {
            [self.renderer processPixelBuffer:_currentBuffer];
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_currentBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"processFrame END");
            return;
        }
    }
}

@end
```