# appendPixelBuffer returning NO for kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, video-processing, avcapturesession

I have the following AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor:

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:frameSize.width] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:frameSize.height] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey];

adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput   sourcePixelBufferAttributes:attributes];
```

And I am trying to append a pixel buffer created from 2 planes (video format type     kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange) using the following:

```
//Pixel buffer
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

/*Pixel options*/
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],     kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                       nil]

void* planesAdress[2] = { (void*)firstFrameGray, (void*)firstFrameUV};
size_t planesWitdh[2] = {640, 320};
size_t planesHeight[2] = { 480, 240};
size_t planesBytesPerRow[2] = { 640, 640};


CVReturn retw = CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, 640, 480, kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, nil, nil, 2,planesAdress, planesWitdh, planesHeight, planesBytesPerRow, NULL, NULL, NULL, &buffer);
```

At this point I can checked the buffer is not null and CVPixelBufferIsPlanar is true.

But every time I try to append the buffer it returns NO for the call (this call is only used for the first frame)

```
[adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

The error is Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x9ad800 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780), NSUnderlyingError=0x9aa200 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (OSStatus error -12780.)", NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

Comment: I forgot to comment that I have also checked that the AVAssetWriter is running and the adaptor is ready for more media. The problem is the error is not clear enough to give me some indications about what Im doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that an AVAssetWriter can take in YUV420p frames? I've seen very good performance myself with encoding BGRA frames captured from OpenGL ES: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9522160/19679

Comment: AVAssetWriter happily accepts kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange (aka 420v). I'd love to know if there's any performance advantage compared to BGRA. As for the OP's problem, it could be the pixel buffer's configuration (have you compared it to what you get back from an AVAssetReader on a good file?) or it could be the adaptor (I've never used them, although apparently there are performance benefits to be had), or even some weird audio session thing (it could happen). Anyhow, I think generating your YUV frames is a grand thing to do & I'd happily look at a sample project.